# OC4J (10.1.2) orion-web.xml

Tags: oc4j, commonj

I try to use CommonJ with OC4J.
I need to write 'resource-ref-mapping' in orion-web.xml

If I have such entry in web.xml:

```
<resource-ref>
    <res-ref-name>tm/PublisherTimerManager</res-ref-name>
    <res-type>commonj.timers.TimerManager</res-type>
    <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
   <res-sharing-scope>Unshareable</res-sharing-scope>
</resource-ref>
```

Then if i undestand right then need in orion-web.xml:

```
  <resource-ref-mapping name="tm/PublisherTimerManager"
                        location="tm/PublisherTimerManager">
        <lookup-context location="commonj.timers.TimerManager">
              <context-attribute name="java.naming.factory.initial"
                                 value="de.myfoo.commonj.timers.FooTimerManagerFactory"/>
        </lookup-context>
  </resource-ref-mapping>
```

Am i right?

Answer (score 0):

CommonJ in OC4J? CommonJ was a collaboration between BEA (now Oracle) and IBM and apart from a few ports (to JBoss I believe) is only available on Weblogic and Websphere.

Comment: Do you know about opensource implementation?